# Attribute not being updated although not rollback appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I update an attribute ('estado') in a Rails App, no error messages. There is no rollback, and the response of the update method is even true. When I inspect the record, the attribute has the old value.

```
[1] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource
=> #<User id: 18, email: "password2@mail.com", created_at: "2019-04-22 10:37:55", updated_at: "2019-04-22 10:37:55", shop_id: nil, seller: false, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, birthday: nil, nationality: nil, document_type: nil, document_number: nil, expiring_date: nil, estado: "pending", admin: false, provider: nil, uid: nil, facebook_picture_url: nil, token: nil, token_expiry: nil>

[2] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource.estado = "Accepted"
=> "Accepted"

[3] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource
=> #<User id: 18, email: "password2@mail.com", created_at: "2019-04-22 10:37:55", updated_at: "2019-04-22 10:37:55", shop_id: nil, seller: false, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, birthday: nil, nationality: nil, document_type: nil, document_number: nil, expiring_date: nil, estado: "pending", admin: false, provider: nil, uid: nil, facebook_picture_url: nil, token: nil, token_expiry: nil>

[4] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ (pry):27
  User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "password2@mail.com"], ["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):27
  User Update (2.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$Pa2Dw8s53F8JSiO617Brxu2zuogK/Mffecokx0iKPnNJkVj05ZqsO"], ["updated_at", "2019-04-22 10:45:50.987192"], ["id", 18]]
  ↳ (pry):27
   (6.0ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ (pry):27
=> true

[5] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> resource
=> #<User id: 18, email: "password2@mail.com", created_at: "2019-04-22 10:37:55", updated_at: "2019-04-22 10:45:50", shop_id: nil, seller: false, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, birthday: nil, nationality: nil, document_type: nil, document_number: nil, expiring_date: nil, estado: "pending", admin: false, provider: nil, uid: nil, facebook_picture_url: nil, token: nil, token_expiry: nil>

[6] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)>
```

Comment: Can you add your User model to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attribute is not being updated in instance on step 2 (seen in 3), this means that there's something wrong with setter.

This can be because of:

1. `attr_accessor`/`attr_writer` for `:estado`
2. custom setter `estado=` not calling `super(new_value)`